# Customise Omnichannel widget

Tags: omnichannel

We have setup Omni-Channel for social post and we have added the omni-channel widget in the console. We would like to add a custom button within the widget to do some action and also show the post details on hover or show content field in the widget.

Are the above possible to add in the widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to above.

In order to add new buttons, we need to customise the entire widget. The content of the post and other details can be added as fields to the widget's compact page layout